# E492: Not an editor command: TagbarToggle

Tags: vim, tagbar

I've succeeded to install `tagbar` with `vim-plug` in my `.vimrc` file. I've also installed a keybinding that use <kbd>F8</kbd> to open `tagbar`. However, each time I use that key, I obtained the error in the title. Could anyone be able to tell me how to fix it?

The keybinding is : `nmap <F8> :TagbarToggle<CR>`

The plugin is build like

```
 call plug#begin() 
 Plug 'majutsushi/tagbar' 

# ...   
 call plug#end()
```

Comment: Show your keybinding and the installed tagbar ?

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス It is done

Comment: Run `:scriptnames` and check if the plugin is well sourced.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you haven't installed the plugin correctly.

did you run install in command mode?

`:PlugInstall`

You also need to install the **ctags** binary since its a dependency if you don't already have it. https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar#dependencies

Comment: You need the ctags binary for the :TagbarToggle command to not give the "Not an editor command: TagbarToggle" error?  Sounds a bit odd.